# T-test Problem, t-value extremely high and p value =0

Tags: t-test

I need to conduct the pair t-test on 2 groups.
Each group has 400 samples.
The data as attached.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9x1xucese7nt63/ttestdata.xlsx?dl=0
However, after the t-test in excel, the t-value is nearly 1300 and p-value is zero.
Is there anything I done wrong?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every value in column A is much (20-30%) higher than it's counterpart from column C. So you do not really need statistical test to conclude that values in column A are greater than in column C.

That is also why *t*-value is extremetly high and *p* is almost 0 (it is **almost** 0, Excel shows 0 due to roundings).

Comment: Is that the t-test valid to conclude that A is greater than B with t-value extremely large? Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly :)